# session handling in android

Tags: android, session

i have been using session handler with php.. now i happen to use this with android but i find it really difficult because i am new to android development. Can anyone give their opinion in android session handling. I searched google but could not find right page to hook up. So any useful page is also useful. I know this is not a place to ask such question because here we need a code to ask you.But i couldnot find a better place to ask this question because i trust www.stackoverflow.com.  Considering this if you could help me, I would be very greatful. 
 Thank you.

Comment: What is "android session handling"?

Comment: i need to handle session so that i could keep trace of every logged in user.

Comment: An Android device usually only has one user. Please edit your question to explain, **completely and precisely** what you mean by "android session handling".

Comment: acutaly i have an android app linked with database. I want to keep the trace of which user made an entry to database through the application. for that i need session handling.

Comment: some would choose to go for `oauth` liked authentication method, where you would give your user a long unique key after he performed a login action correctly, and he attaches this unique key whenever he communicates with your server, so your server would know who is performing any actions.